# Is it possible to delete message from Kafka? If yes, what are the steps I need to follow?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to maintain a very large Kafka, and delete selective messages. Is it possible to do that operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't delete single messages in Kafka. Messages will be deleted as part of a log segment which will be cleaned up as a whole based on your retention policy.